# Pin not falling back to default state after button is pressed

Tags: gpio

I am having a simple circuit which is only supposed to give back the status of a certain pin on the push of a button that puts a voltage on input pin 16. When I push the button, the state goes to 1 as intended but when I release the button it does not fall back to 0. Once I disconnect the pin from the + side, the state falls back. There are no capacitors or anything used that would have residual voltage to cause that.  What is wrong here?

```
from machine import Pin
import utime

valveStatus = Pin(16, Pin.IN)
print("Intitial Status:",valveStatus.value())

while True:
   print(valveStatus.value())
   print("valve is closed")
enter code here   utime.sleep(0.5)
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: "What is wrong here?" Detail missing!

Comment: I need to know why the pin is not falling back to 0 after the voltage is no longer applied to the input. Is it the code? Do I have to reset the pin somehow?

Comment: What have you connected to what? We don't even know what hardware you are using.

Comment: *`"why the pin is not falling back to 0 after the voltage is no longer applied"`*.  Not picking on you, but your question shows no effort, and insufficient detail. Please read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and consider including a [schematic](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/how-do-i-add-a-schematic-to-my-question) if that's the limit of your verbal skills.

Answer (score 3):

You are mistaken in believing that a GPIO has a default state.

A GPIO will tend to stay in a state unless it is driven to a different state.

If you want a default state add a pull down to ground if you want default low or add a pull up to 3V3 if you want default high.

The Pi and Pico have internal pulls which you can set in software or you can add your own external pulls in the form of resistors.

If you use external pulls use quite large resistances (say 10k to 50k) to ensure they can easily be overridden as needed.